# DateHistogram with DateReduction -> editing x axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time, histograms

I have a list of dates spanning over multiple years (i.e.):

```
datelist = {DateObject[{1995, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", 
"Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1996, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1996, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1996, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1996, 3, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1996, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 2, 23, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 3, 16, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 12, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 12, 19, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1997, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1998, 1, 30, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{1998, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 10, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2000, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2001, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2001, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2001, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2001, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2001, 12, 20, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 2, 12, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 3, 29, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 12, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2002, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2003, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2003, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2003, 2, 16, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2003, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2003, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`],DateObject[{2004, 12, 26, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 12, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2005, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2006, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2006, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2006, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2006, 12, 27, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2006, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2007, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2007, 3, 18, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2007, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2008, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2008, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2009, 2, 18, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2009, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2009, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2009, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2009, 3, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2010, 1, 26, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2011, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2011, 3, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2011, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2011, 11, 19, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2012, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2012, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2012, 11, 14, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2012, 12, 22, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2013, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2013, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2013, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 11, 16, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 11, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2014, 11, 27, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2015, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2015, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2015, 4, 14, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2016, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2016, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2018, 1, 26, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2018, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2018, 11, 18, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2018, 12, 7, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2018, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2019, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2019, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2019, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2019, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2019, 12, 9, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 21, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 11, 26, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], DateObject[{2020, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`]};
```

To plot with DateHistogram with the option of monthly bins using DateReduction:

```
DateHistogram[datelist,"Month","Probability",DateReduction->"Year"]
```

This produces:

[image]

I would like to plot this data from September to May. Do you have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You mean Sept of last year to May of current year? To clear any ambiguities, could you please add `datelist` to your post?

Comment: Sure. I clarified my question.

Comment: Please add copy-paste-able data not an image. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Done it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple processing of the month entries in input dates gives as the desired histogram (except the bin labels):

```
rotatedDH = DateHistogram[MapAt[Mod[# - 8, 12, 1] &, datelist, {All, 1, 2}], 
  "Month", DateReduction -> "Year"]
```

[image]

To fix the bin labels, define a replacement rule to post-process `rotatedDH`:

```
reLabel = AssociationThread @@ Map[StringTake[#, 3] &] @ 
  {#, RotateLeft[#, 8]} & @ DateAndTime`MonthList["Gregorian"];

rotatedDH /. reLabel
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach using [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) + [`BarChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html)

```
shiftedShortMonthNames = RotateLeft[#, 8] & @ 
   StringTake[DateAndTime`MonthList["Gregorian"], 3]
```

> {"Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug"}

```
countsByMonth = Counts[#["MonthNameShort"] & /@ datelist]
```

> <|"Dec" -> 25, "Jan" -> 35, "Mar" -> 16, "Feb" -> 22, "Oct" -> 1,
> "Apr" -> 5, "Nov" -> 12|>

```
shiftedCounts = Join[AssociationThread[shiftedShortMonthNames, 0], countsByMonth]
```

> <|"Sep" -> 0, "Oct" -> 1, "Nov" -> 12, "Dec" -> 25, "Jan" -> 35,
> "Feb" -> 22, "Mar" -> 16, "Apr" -> 5, "May" -> 0, "Jun" -> 0, "Jul" -> 0, "Aug" -> 0|>

```
BarChart[shiftedCounts, ChartLabels -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> 0]
```

[image]